# Create hackage package that can be installed with stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

When running `stack sdist` in my project directory, the `stack.yaml` file isn't included in the tarball (this seems to [be expected](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2105)).

Consequently, when I upload the tarball to hackage, then `stack install mypackage` it complains about missing dependencies (`extra-deps`) which I specified in the `stack.yaml` file.

```
$ stack install pandoc-placetable

Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-5.17 from implicit global project's config file: ~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      spreadsheet: needed (>=0.1.3 && <0.1.4), not present in build plan (latest applicable is 0.1.3.4)
    needed for package: pandoc-placetable-0.4

--  While attempting to add dependency,
    Could not find package spreadsheet in known packages

Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/maurobieg/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
- spreadsheet-0.1.3.4
```

Or what's the recommended way to make a hackage package `stack`-installable if it has further hackage dependencies?

**Update**: I just added `extra-source-files: stack.yaml` to the cabal file and the `stack.yaml` is indeed included in the tarbal of the newly published version. Nevertheless, `stack install pandoc-placetable-0.4.1` still comes up with the same error.

I could also just tell people who don't want to install `cabal-install` on their system to clone from GitHub, then build with `stack`. Is that the recommended approach for tiny packages? Or should I ask them to include the dependency of `pandoc-placetable` (i.e. `spreadsheet`) in their global `stack.yaml`? Smells like polluting a global file...

Comment: Does the suggestion (`extra-source-files: stack.yaml`) in the thread you linked work? I would expect it to. Hackage package are not meant to be 'stack-installable' (stack doesn't do anything but call other programs which do all the work, so 'stack-installable' is just 'cabal-installable'), or you are meant to get the `stack.yaml` from your resolver (remember, package maintainers will likely want to support multiple compile version and will have multiple `stack.yaml`).

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, I'd recommend getting your package into Stackage: https://github.com/fpco/stackage#add-your-package

Comment: @user2407038 `extra-source-files` doesn't help, see my update.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman my package consists of only one source code file, it's a really small pandoc filter that's not going to change much. Are we supposed to push small stuff like that to stackage as well? Won't there be too much administrative overhead for you guys? Also, I'll have to release a new package every few months, whenever the next `lts` comes along, even if my dependencies and code don't change at all, right? (please correct me if I'm wrong and take it as feedback about what information I gathered as a casual haskell dev)

Comment: I think the answer you're looking forward is to first stack unpack your package, then stack install inside the new directory.

Comment: Relevant stack issue about using stack.yaml from hackage package: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2122

Comment: Thanks @mgsloan, that's exactly my issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @mgsloan in the comments above: There's an open [stack issue about using stack.yaml from hackage package](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2122).

I guess until it's fixed I'll just tell people to clone from GitHub (or as mentioned by @MichaelSnoyman to `stack unpack`) and then `cd` into the newly created directory and `stack install` there.